# Tree dataTipFunction tooltip Change position,Flex3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, air

I am doing dataTipFunction on Tree in Flex3 Air,

At present the tooltip hides the present node, i need to reposition the tooltip above the node, how can change the x,y position of the tooltip.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

The way I did this was to add the **toolTipShown** listener on the tree itemRenderer, not on the tree.  I have a **[blog post](http://flexdevtips.blogspot.com/2010/03/tree-item-tooltips.html)** that shows you how to do it, including the code for positioning the tooltip below or above the node.

Answer (score 0):

Hook into the tooltipShow event on the Tree and move the tooltip yourself (a reference to the tooltip is in the event)

[tooltipShow](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event:toolTipShow)

You might need to do a bit of logic to position it correctly, and you'll probably want to check if repositioning it would move it off screen and move it below instead in that case.